# Symfony translator and Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a templates library based on Twig, but I have not installed the whole Symfony library. I want to use Symfony's translation in my project, is this possible without installing the whole Symfony? Currently I have imported

```
 "twig/twig":      "~1.0",     
 "symfony/translation":    "^3.0",
 "symfony/yaml":      "^3.0",
```

If this is possible, how do I have to "enable" the translator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the translator as stand-alone component. As described in the [doc here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/usage.html):

```
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\ArrayLoader;

$translator = new Translator('fr_FR');
$translator->addLoader('array', new ArrayLoader());
$translator->addResource('array', array(
    'Symfony is great!' => 'J\'aime Symfony!',
), 'fr_FR');

var_dump($translator->trans('Symfony is great!'));
```

So you need to make a mechanism to load the catalog and use the translator in TWIG as a custom filter.

hope this help

Comment: Yes,this is really helpful! Only, I encounter another problem, my path is vendor\symfony\translation\... and I get the error  Interface 'Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface' not found. Maybe I miss installing something?

Comment: seems correct. I have the interface under the path you say.

Comment: Do you need to 'require' any of the translator's files, or you configure the dependencies in a different way? It just doesn't find the TranslatorInterface required in Translator.php

Comment: the interface is correctly in the repo https://github.com/symfony/translation where is downloaded the package. Try to reload the php autoloader or check for the file in the autoloader too.

Comment: Thank you! This was the problem, I had to require the `vendor/autoload.php` file before any of the other code or files.

Comment: Well! I was supposing you use the composer autorloader